# Cleaning/Changing url

Tags: html, xslt

Exporting XML with hyperlinked fields from MsAccess leads to "url's" with a starting en ending "#" how do i remove them from the URL part and the text part with Xslt so how do i clean:

```html
<a href="#https://web.site.nl/dataset#">#https://web.site.nl/dataset#</a></div>
```

So how to wipe the #

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the first and the last character are extraneous, just remove them:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="substring(@href, 2, string-length(@href) - 2)" />
    <a href="{$url}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$url"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```